# Partial screenshot selenium python firefox webdriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, ubuntu, firefox, webdriver

Im using ubuntu server 16.04 x64
And im trying to take partial screenshot of image in the page.
But its taking screenshot all of page.

My code is:

```
qr = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('img[alt="result-img"]')

return qr.screenshot_as_base64
```

im using python3, selenium, firefox 61.x v.
Trying to take element by xPath, but didn't work. Its takes all page screenshot.

on this image positioned other few images by css "position: absolute" thats why i want to take screenshot.